# How to stop a tornado web application?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to test this 'hello world' of python (with tornado) on ubuntu:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    httpserver.stop()
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

My command line to run this web app:
python hello.py

However I can run this 'hello.py' only once. Now i'm changing the code and wish to run 'hello.py' again. I think that i need to stop the previously run instance of 'hello.py' coz it is taking port 8888. But just don't have the clue how to do this.

I try to "import tornado.httpserver" to use the function "httpserver.stop()" but python reports at terminal that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 14, in <module>
    httpserver.stop()
NameError: name 'httpserver' is not defined
```

I try "HTTPServer.stop()" also, but it gives the same error!!!

Comment: You should use `tornado.httpserver.stop()` since you have imported `tornado.httpserver` module

Comment: tornado.httpserver is the package isn't it? i tried to use tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer.stop() but it failed 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop Tornado web server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375220/how-do-i-stop-tornado-web-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your terminal isn't attached you can just kill the pid, if it is Ctrl + c.

related link:
http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/87bc2451d79fa110/30665b2717397152?pli=1

Comment: yeah but that is manual. i want the code to stop tornado automatically to apply the changes in python code when editted.

Comment: no. you will need to restart the server. or send a SIGHUP maybe?

Comment: check this out http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/87bc2451d79fa110/30665b2717397152

Answer (score 3):

A. [Importing in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) is different from java\C#. To import specified terms you should write something like

```
   from tornado import ioloop,web,httpserver
```

or use items as imported( i.e. with `tornado.` prefix )

B. When you are `calling ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` this function will run until it's catches an exception, process is closed or one of registered handles calls `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()`. Also it could restart when code of any imported module is changed.