# Tornado long polling requests

Tags: python, tornado, long-polling

Below is the most simple example of my issue:

When a request is made it will print `Request via GET <__main__.MainHandler object at 0x104041e10>` and then the request will remain open. Good! However, when you make another request it does not call the `MainHandler.get` method until the first connection has finished.

How can I get multiple requests into the `get` method while having them remain long-polling. I'm passing arguments with each request that will get different results from a pub/sub via redis. Issue is that I only get one connection in at a time. Whats wrong? And why is this blocking other requests?

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import os


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        print 'Request via GET', self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler)])

    try:
        application.listen(int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

**Diagram Left**: As described in issue above. The requests are not handled in the fashion requested in right diagram.
**Diagram on the right** I need the requests (a-d) to be handled by the RequestHandler and then wait for the pub/sub to announce their data.

```
       a  b   c   d
       +  +   +   +                        ++          a    b   c   d
       |  |   |   |                        ||          +    +   +   +
       |  |   |   |                        ||          |    |   |   |
       |  |   |   |                        ||          |    |   |   |
       |  |   |   |                        ||          |    |   |   |
       |  v   v   v                        ||          |    |   |   |
   +---|-----------------------------+     ||    +-----|----|---|---|------------------+
   |   |                             |     ||    |     |    |   |   |                  |
   |   +               RequestHandler|     ||    |     +    +   +   +     RequestHan.  |
   |   |                             |     ||    |     |    |   |   |                  |
   +---|-----------------------------+     ||    +-----|----|---|---|------------------+
   +---|-----------------------------+     ||    +-----|----|---|---|------------------+
   |   |                             |     ||    |     |    |   |   |                  |
   |   +                Sub/Pub Que  |     ||    |     v    +   v   v         Que      |
   |   |                             |     ||    |          |                          |
   +---|-----------------------------+     ||    +----------|--------------------------+
   +---|-----------------------------+     ||    +----------|--------------------------+
       |                                   ||               |
       |                 Finished          ||               |               Finished
       v                                   ||               v
                                           ||
                                           ||
                                           ||
                                           ||
                                           ||
                                           ||
                                           ||
                                           ++
```

If this is accomplishable with another programming language please let me know.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous:

> tornado.web.asynchronous(method)
>
> ...
>
> If this decorator is given, the response is not finished when the
>   method returns. It is up to the request handler to call self.finish()
>   to finish the HTTP request. Without this decorator, the request is
>   automatically finished when the get() or post() method returns.

You have to finish `get` method explicitly:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.options

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        print 'Request via GET', self
        self.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler)])

    try:
        application.listen(options.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. However, I'm looking for a way to perform a long polling request. Not just close the connection but keep it alive until I have data for it. And the data will be fed from redis sub/pub and will be different for every connected client.

Comment: @StevePeak Did you find any solution to this because I'm trying to do the same in tornado. I need to create a long polling endpoint in tornado and return data when I get something from redis. I'm very new to tornado and async programming in general.