# Stopping a tornado application

Tags: python, tornado

Let's take the hello world application in the Tornado home page:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  application.listen(8888)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Is there a way, after the IOloop has been started and without stopping it, to essentially stop the application and start another one (on the same port or on another)?

I saw that I can add new application (listening on different ports) at runtime, but I do not know how I could stop existing ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Application.listen()` method actually creates a `HTTPServer` and calls its `listen()` medthod. `HTTPServer` objects has `stop()` method which is probably what you need. But in order to do it you have to explicitly create `HTTPServer` object in your script.

```
server = HTTPServer(application)
server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

#somewhere in your code
server.stop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a gist about how to gracefully and safely shutdown the tornado ioloop.

https://gist.github.com/nicky-zs/6304878

However, you can refer to this implementation to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [@**Alex Shkop**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23778634/4541045) a few years later, as of Tornado 4.3 `.listen()` returns a reference to its `HTTPServer`!

https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.listen

```py
server = app.listen()
... # later
server.stop()
```

Further, if you're working in a Jupyter notebook and for some reason need a Tornado server, you can `try` to close the `HTTPServer` before you recreate it to avoid `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` on re-running the cell

```py
# some Jupyter cell
#
import tornado.web

try:
    server.stop()  # NameError on first cell run
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"server not started to stop: {repr(ex)}")
else:  # did not raise NameError: server was running
    print(f"successfully stopped server: {server}")

app = tornado.web.Application(...)
server = app.listen(9006)  # arbitrary listening port
```