# How to stop (and restart!) a Tornado server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I want to be able to stop and restart a Tornado server for testing and demo purposes. But it doesn't seem to release the port.

The following code is based on [answer showing how to properly stop Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17325148/487992). I just added the code at the bottom that tries to restart Tornado. It fails with "error: Address in use" exception. I even added a call to `ioloop.close()` but that didn't help.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import threading
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world!\n")

def start_tornado(*args, **kwargs):
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    print "Starting Torando"
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    print "Tornado finished"

def stop_tornado():
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.stop)
    ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.close) # I added this but it didn't help.
    print "Asked Tornado to exit"

def main():

    t = threading.Thread(target=start_tornado)
    t.start()

    time.sleep(1)

    stop_tornado()
    t.join()
    print "Tornado thread stopped."

    t = threading.Thread(target=start_tornado) # Attempt restart.
    t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Starting Torando
Asked Tornado to exit
 Tornado finished
Tornado thread stopped.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/home/mudd/musl/Python-2.7.11.install/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/mudd/musl/Python-2.7.11.install/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "./test_tonado_restart.py", line 17, in start_tornado
    application.listen(8888)
  File "/home/mudd/musl/Python-2.7.11.install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1825, in listen
    server.listen(port, address)
  File "/home/mudd/musl/Python-2.7.11.install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/mudd/musl/Python-2.7.11.install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 196, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/home/mudd/musl/Python-2.7.11.install/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 98] Address in use
```

Comment: I don't think you need to manage your own threads in tornado. The ioloop does that for you, I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use threads like this unless you *really* need to - they complicate things quite a bit. For tests, use `tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase` or `AsyncHTTPTestCase`.

To free the port, you need to stop the `HTTPServer`, not just the `IOLoop`. In fact, you might not even need to stop the `IOLoop` at all. (but normally I'd restart everything by just letting the process exit and restarting it from scratch).

A non-threaded version of your example would be something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world!\n")

def start_app(*args, **kwargs):
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    server = application.listen(8888)
    print "Starting app"
    return server

def stop_tornado():
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.stop)
    print "Asked Tornado to exit"

def main():
    server = start_app()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(
        datetime.timedelta(seconds=1),
        stop_tornado)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    print "Tornado finished"
    server.stop()

    # Starting over
    start_app()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. What will Tornado do if anything happens to you?