# Stopping the Mesa server

Tags: python, server, localhost

I am a new user to the `mesa` python package and I noticed that when running examples we can do `server.launch()` which will start running the server (in a localhost address) stuff so that we can run the example in the browser as a client program. How do I stop this server now?
I checked everywhere in the documentation and cannot find it. It is really annoying that I have to restart my computer for stopping it.

Comment: I don't know this module but most servers can be run in console/terminal and later they can be stoped using `Ctrl+C` in console/terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If You dive into implementation of `Mesa` module, unfortunately it looks like there is no possibility to stop server.

But object `ModularServer` depends on `Tornado` object. So maybe You can find answer here ["How do I stop Tornado web server?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375220/how-do-i-stop-tornado-web-server)